# What is the (logical) relationship between an measurement instrument's validity and responsiveness?

Tags: measurement, validity

The three major criteria for the quality of a measurement instrument are validity, reliability, and responsiveness. I understand validity and reliability, but I have trouble understanding the need to distinguish responsiveness.

As quoted in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2021.06.002, responsiveness "refers to the ability of a measurement instrument to detect change over time in the construct to be measured". Doesn't this mean that responsiveness implies validity and reliability, which would make it redundant?

Answer (score 5):

This issue here is that "validity" can be a very loose concept.

Take *anxiety* as an example. Anxiousness is both a trait (some people are more anxious than others) and a state (everyone's level of anxiety fluctuates over time). You're correct that a measure of state anxiety that is valid and reliable will by definition also be responsive as well, but often people will fail to specify if they're trying to measure the state or the trait, and so you may have an instrument that's a valid measure of trait anxiety, and a reliable measure of trait anxiety, but is not responsive, because it doesn't measure state anxiety.

So the advice you quote could be rephrased as follows:

> If you're trying to measure a state, make sure you're not accidentally measuring a trait instead.

How do you make sure you're measuring the state and not the trait? By ensuring that your instrument is responsive.

Comment: I would argue that this again is simply a matter of validity. An instrument that measures "trait anxiety" (i.e., a pure trait measure) is not valid for measuring state anxiety, and hence, one would not expect it to be "responsive" to state fluctuations in anxiety in the first place. In other words, the concept of "responsiveness" is redundant with the concept of validity. Scale validation (in particular: assessing factorial validity) would include finding out whether a scale measures a trait-like or a state-like concept (e.g., by applying longitudinal latent state-trait models).

Comment: See, for example: Steyer, R., Majcen, A. M., Schwenkmezger, P., & Buchner, A. (1989). A latent state-trait anxiety model and its application to determine consistency and specificity coefficients. Anxiety Research, 1(4), 281-299.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely true, but I think "validity" in this sense is often too broad to be practically useful, so calling out responsiveness as a separate criterion is definitely a useful exercise.

Answer (score 4):

In the abstract, the authors say

> responsiveness is considered longitudinal validity, which refers to
> the degree to which an instrument is able to measure change in the
> construct to be measured.

So, it seems like it is one more kind of validity to add to the list (construct validity, face validity, content validity etc.).

Then a question is "can a measurement be reliable and valid in other ways, but not responsive?"  However, each of these criteria is a continuum, not a dichotomy.

I'm not sure of the answer, but one thought regards ceiling and floor effects. That is, if a person is at the ceiling or floor of an instrument, then that instrument can't measure negative/positive change.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. Valid measurement of a construct implies that the measurement instrument should also be sensitive to changes in that construct across time. How could a measure be valid for measuring the construct if it didn't indicate changes over time in the construct? In that sense, I'd say "responsiveness" is redundant with validity. I also had never heard of "responsiveness" as a "major criterion" for measurement quality.